# updating List View from a Custom List adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom list view that implements list adapter and it has two buttons for deleting and editing for each entry in the list. The delete button works fine but the edit button accept changes but doesn't reflect it in the list until the activity is recreated by going back and and back to it again. I have tried `notifyDataSetChanged()`, `invalidate`, `refreshDrawable` but nothing works. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my Adapter_Settings code.

```
public class Adapter_Settings extends BaseAdapter implements   ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> ContactList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;
    private SaveValues sv = new SaveValues();
    private ListView listView;
    CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"New Contact", "Contact List"};

    String emerConName, emerConNum;

    public Adapter_Settings(ArrayList<String> ContactList, Context context,ListView list) {
        this.ContactList = ContactList;
        this.context = context;
        this.listView=list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ContactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ContactList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_list, null);
        }

        final TextView Contact_list = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Contact_settings);
        Contact_list.setText(ContactList.get(position));

        ImageButton DeleteBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        ImageButton EditBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);

        DeleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println(Contact_list.getText().toString());
                System.out.println(position);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this contact?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String delcon;
                        delcon = Contact_list.getText().toString();
                        if (delcon.equals(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName1, context) + "\n" + (sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactNumber1, context)))) {
                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactName1, ConstantValues.skipper, context);
                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactNumber1, ConstantValues.skipper, context);
                            //                   System.out.println(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName1, context));
                        } else if (delcon.equals(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName2, context) + "\n" + (sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactNumber2, context)))) {
                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactName2, ConstantValues.skipper, context);
                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactNumber2, ConstantValues.skipper, context);
                            //                  System.out.println(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName2, context));
                        } else if (delcon.equals(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName3, context) + "\n" + (sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactNumber3, context)))) {
                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactName3, ConstantValues.skipper, context);
                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactNumber3, ConstantValues.skipper, context);
                            //                System.out.println(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName3, context));
                        } else if (delcon.equals(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName4, context) + "\n" + (sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactNumber4, context)))) {
                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactName4, ConstantValues.skipper, context);
                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactNumber4, ConstantValues.skipper, context);
                            //              System.out.println(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName4, context));
                        }
                        ContactList.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        EditBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String editcon = Contact_list.getText().toString();

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.Add_Contact);
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                builder1.setTitle("New Contact");
                                builder1.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.defaultcontact_popup, null)).setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                        Dialog d = (Dialog) dialog;
                                        EditText newnameview, newphoneview;
                                        // System.out.println("=======CONTACT ADDED=============");
                                        newnameview = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.ConName);
                                        newphoneview = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.ConNumber);
                                        emerConName = newnameview.getText().toString();
                                        emerConNum = newphoneview.getText().toString();
                                        if (editcon.equals(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName1, context) + "\n" + (sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactNumber1, context)))) {
                                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactName1, emerConName, context);
                                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactNumber1, emerConNum, context);
                                            //Contact_list.setText(emerConName + "\n" + emerConNum);

                                        } else if (editcon.equals(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName2, context) + "\n" + (sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactNumber2, context)))) {
                                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactName2, emerConName, context);
                                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactNumber2, emerConNum, context);
                                            //Contact_list.setText(emerConName + "\n" + emerConNum);

                                        } else if (editcon.equals(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName3, context) + "\n" + (sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactNumber3, context)))) {
                                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactName3, emerConName, context);
                                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactNumber3, emerConNum, context);
                                            //Contact_list.setText(emerConName + "\n" + emerConNum);

                                        } else if (editcon.equals(sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactName4, context) + "\n" + (sv.GetValue(ConstantValues.ContactNumber4, context)))) {
                                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactName4, emerConName, context);
                                            sv.SaveStringValues(ConstantValues.ContactNumber4, emerConNum, context);
                                            //Contact_list.setText(emerConName+"\n"+emerConNum );

                                        }


                                    }


                                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // System.out.println("=========CONTACT REMOVED==========");
                                    }

                                });
                                builder1.show();

                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); //Crating a new intent to PICK contact from list
                                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); //Setting the type to fetch all attributes of selected contact
                                //ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(intent, ConstantValues.PHONE_REQUEST_CODE);// starting the intent with a unique value of PHONE_REQUEST_CODE

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```